# Copy 3rd Cell from under Same Row Where Col B is not empty

Tags: excel, vba, copy, offset

I have been trying to create a function which checks that if Col"B" <> Empty then copy the third cell which is under the same row.

I have this Data:

[image]

Where from i want to copy the Col"D" highlighted cells and paste them into same row where Col"B" <> empty.

Here is the final result. Your help will be appreciated in this regards.

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyPasting()
    
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim n As Long
        
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        With ws
            LastRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            
        For r = LastRow To 2 Step -2
                If .Cells(r, "B") <> "" Then
                .Rows(r + "D").Copy
                .Rows(r + "D").PasteSpecial
    
            n = n + 1
            End If
            Next
    End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub testRetOffset3()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngV As Range, rngFin As Range, c As Range
  Set sh = ActiveSheet  'use here the sheet you need
  lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last sheet row
  On Error Resume Next  'if not empty cells in column, it will not return the range and raise an error
  Set rngV = sh.Range("B2:B" & lastR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If rngV Is Nothing Then Exit Sub  'stop the code if run on a wrong sheet, without empty cells in column B:B
  For Each c In rngV.cells          'iterate between the discontinuous range cells
    If rngFin Is Nothing Then       'if the final range is not set (first time)
        Set rngFin = c.Offset(3, 2) 'set the range = the Offset necessary cell
    Else
        Set rngFin = Union(rngFin, c.Offset(3, 2)) 'make a Union between existing range and the Offset necessary cell
    End If
  Next
  If Not rngFin Is Nothing Then  'copy both ranges in consecutive columns
        rngV.Copy sh.Range("F2")  
        rngFin.Copy sh.Range("G2")
  End If
End Sub
```

It will return in columns F:G, starting from the second row. It is easy to modify the range where to return...

You can even clear the existing processed columns and return in B:C, or in another sheet.

**Edited**:
In order to solve the last request, please use the next code:

```
Sub testRetOffsetMoreRows()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngV As Range, rngFin As Range, A As Range
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  On Error Resume Next
  Set rngV = sh.Range("A2:D" & lastR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If rngV Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  For Each A In rngV.Areas  'iterate between the range areas
    If rngFin Is Nothing Then
        Set rngFin = A.cells(1,2).Offset(3, 3) 'use the second cell of the area
    Else
        Set rngFin = Union(rngFin, A.cells(1,2).Offset(3, 3))
    End If
  Next
  If Not rngFin Is Nothing Then
        rngV.Copy sh.Range("H2")
        rngFin.Copy sh.Range("L2")
  End If
End Sub
```

But take care to have continuous ranges when have a value in column B:B. Otherwise, the code may fail... The areas property will return differently.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working great for just two column data but how to add further column if i need to pull these data as well https://ibb.co/n655WG7

Comment: @Valiant OK. I will post a piece of code able to deal with it. It will use `Areas` property...

Comment: @Valiant Didn't you find time to test the updated code? If tested, didn't it return what you need?

Comment: I am testing it is giving an error that is `The Action won't work on multiple selections` i do not know why i have been finding the solution from google. But nothing found. I have just single sheet in the file that is Sheet1

Comment: @Valiant I tested the new code and it works as expected. But I told you in the comment after the code "But take care to have continuous ranges when have a value in column B:B". And I tried explaining why...

Comment: I got it missed that note. Thank you so much. I read you have updated this.

Comment: But it does not paste the Col"E" data i have attached 2 pictures with data and code. https://ibb.co/P6PbvxY
https://ibb.co/FbR9vCH

Comment: I am driving now. I will be able to look here after sume hours, when I will be at home...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234573/discussion-between-faneduru-and-valiant).

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure where you wanted the output, this will put it into a sheet called "Sheet2". (You'll have to make that before running the code it won't create it for you.)

```
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim srcWS As Worksheet
    Dim destWS As Worksheet
    
    Set srcWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set destWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    With srcWS
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        j = 2
        For i = 2 To lr
            If .Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then
                destWS.Cells(j, 1).Value = .Cells(i, 2).Value
                destWS.Cells(j, 2).Value = .Cells(i, 4).Offset(2, 0).Value
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
```

If you need the colors copied over as well then use this:

```
.Cells(i, 4).Offset(2, 0).Copy
destWS.Cells(j, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

instead of:

```
destWS.Cells(j, 2).Value = .Cells(i, 4).Offset(2, 0).Value
```